# Pass variable to a javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I want to pass a variable to a callback function in JavaScript but I haven't found an easy and straightforward way (without using global variables etc). Here's my code:

```
$(".delete-sign").click(function(event) {
    var imgId = this.id;
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(response) {
        if (response == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url:'delete_keyframes.php',
                type:"POST",
                data: { id: imgId },
                success:function(){ alert("Deleted keyframe"); }
            });
            $("#img-div-"+imgId).remove();
        }
    });     
});
```

I want to pass the **imgId** variable inside the callback function. What should I do?

Comment: You're already doing it, and it's not global

Comment: Yeap, I just solved my problem! I used this.id inside the callback and it didn't work and I thought it needed something more elaborate. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to *pass* it. You can just use it.

Comment: If you want to close over `this`, you'd need to use an ES6 arrow function.